# Getting rid of <br> tags in parsing XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm parsing the XML from BART's website at http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml
I want to parse a single station, lets say Millbrae:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml');

foreach($xml->station as $station){
 if($station->name=="Millbrae"){
  foreach($station->eta as $eta) {
    echo $eta->destination;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $eta->estimate;
    echo "<br>";
    }}
  }
?>
```

That outputs the correct data from Millbrae, but the output has a lot of 
 tags-its as if it outputs the entire xml file until it gets to Millbrae, rather than just Millbrae. 
Is there a way to get rid of all those 
 tags? I am just learning php and html, so I am not even sure if I'm asking this question properly.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a typo in the question or are there really only two closing braces?

Comment: could you provide sample output?

Comment: the output when I run it from the command line gives a bunch of <br> tags. And when I access it online, it gives a bunch of whitespace then the output down at the bottom of the page rather than the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [PHP <sup>manual</sup>: strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

`function strip_tags` — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml');

foreach($xml->station as $station) {
 if($station->name=="Millbrae") {
  foreach($station->eta as $eta) {

    echo strip_tags ($eta->destination); //use strip_tags here
    echo "<br>";
    echo strip_tags ($eta->estimate); //use strip_tags here
    echo "<br>";
    }
  }
 }
```

?>